# Why is the compiler not giving a compiler error since I am comparing int[] array with a string value?

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison, data-conversion

In the commented line compiler does not give any errors and I'm confused why? Should I not have done and casting? I guess not since it seems to be working just fine but I don't know why!

```
public class Stack {

 int[] array;

        public Stack(int n)
        {
            maxsize = n;
            length =  maxsize;
            array = new int[maxsize];
            top = 0;

        } 

         public void Delete()
         {
            if( array[0] != '\0' ) // \0 is string while array is of type int
            {
                array[top-1] = 0;
                top= top-1;
            }

         }
}
```

Comment: The value is a `char` not a `String`  , and a `char` can be compared to an `int` .

Comment: If you try to compare `array[0]` to "Hello I am a String" then you will get an error

Answer (score 4):

`'\0'` is a **char**, not a string.

[You can compare `int` with a `char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

`char` is a `16-bit unsigned integer`

Comment: You should comment that `'\0'` is some sort of control character in Java.

Comment: It doesn't matter about control char or not. It's just a matter of fact that in java char can compared to int

Answer (score 0):

You are actually comparing an int with a char, because you use single brackets.

This is possible, since typecasting allows you to convert a higher data type into lower.

Comparing a String to an int, or int[] for that matter, gives you a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

'/0' is a char not a string, and when you are comparing them, then that char is automatically converted to int value (which is its ASCII value), and there is no exception.